# How do I make EJS not render HTML comments

Tags: express, ejs

Quick question! The docs don't seem to mention this anywhere (in doubt if this even is possible) - but is there an option in EJS to make it NOT render HTML comments in my EJS templates?

So let's say I have this EJS:

```
<article>
    <!-- this is my paragraph -->
    <p>Most awesome paragraph evah!</p>
</article>
```

And when express renders that template using EJS, I would like this as output:

```
<article>
    <p>Most awesome paragraph evah!</p>
</article>
```

so I can have my comments in my EJS and not in my rendered html. Is this possible? And if so - where do I configure this in an environment like express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that EJS comes with <%# I am some comment! %> built in, was looking at the wrong kind of comments in my templates :)

(But still, if this is possible to not render HTML comments I'm eager to know! I hate having comments in the client...)